# How do i go off this warning Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, split, count, character

in my code below i want to alter each result according to  `$b`  quantity  example

```
for($i = 0; $i<3; $i++)
  1 $pins[$b] 1234 
  2 $pins[$b] 5678
  3 $pins[$b] uncompleted
```

This is my code:

```
$pin = "12345678910";
# split string in pieces with 4 characters
$disp = str_split($pin, 4);
for($i = 0; $i<3; $i++){
    # loop on all pin
    foreach($disp[$i] as $pins)     {
        # length is not 4
        if(strlen($pins) != 4)     { 
            echo "uncompleted";
        } else {
            echo "$pin[$i] ";
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting a warning:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

How do resolve it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this, If you are using for loop then do not need to add foreach also, `str_split` splits a string into parts of array and then we have to go through loop to check which array of object has length of string is 4.

```
$pin = "12345678910";
$disp = str_split($pin, 4);
$count = count($disp);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
  if(strlen($disp[$i]) != 4)     { 
    echo "uncompleted";
  } else {
    echo $disp[$i];
  }
}
```

Thanks i hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @Eniedi Monday If it solved your issue or helpfull please do upvote.

Answer (score 2):

`$disp` is not multi-dimensional so you don't need the `for($i`.

```
$pin = "12345678910";
# split string in pieces with 4 characters
$disp = str_split($pin, 4);
foreach($disp as $pin)     {
    # length is not 4
    if(strlen($pin) != 4)     { 
        echo "uncompleted";
    } else {
        echo $pin;
    }
}
```

The `foreach($disp[$i]` is/was trying to iterate over an `array` or `object` but `$disp[$i]` is a string.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/O2osD